# keep title short

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Suggestion to use contracted terms in titles (of a book or something) to make them shorter (not too long):

> Prefer contracted terms **to keep titles short**.

Does the selected phrase sound natural?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't much like seeing the verb ***prefer*** used in an ***imperative*** construction (with assumed but unstated subject ***you***). I'd prefer to see ***Use** contracted terms [in order] to keep titles short*.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! What if I change the sentence like this: Prefer contracted terms to uncontracted ones. Is it still less "attractive" that using something like "Better use ... than ..."?)

Comment: You can change it as much as you like - it'll still be syntactically valid, but I still won't like it for the reason given above. And although it might be tedious to dig out the relevant usage statistics from something like Google Books, I'm absolutely certain that ***use*** will be far more common than ***prefer*** in imperative constructions - even after allowing for the fact that ***to use*** is a more common verb than ***to prefer*** in general. You can make whichever stylistic choice you want; I'm just pointing out that ***prefer*** wouldn't be *my* choice here.

Comment: The *grammar* of the phrase only sounds natural if it ***is*** a title. If it's ***not*** a title, then it's using phrasing appropriate for a title in an inappropriate way. The overall grammar aside, I agree with the other comments: ***prefer*** is awkward—even in a title. You can't instruct somebody to ***prefer*** something, only to ***do*** something or to ***choose*** something or to ***use*** something.